# Mysql Trigger - when specific column values change then run trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, ajax, triggers

is this possible to set a trigger on a specific column .eg i have a table name product_deals

there i store deal info.. all field are updated from front-end side through ajax.. only last  column updated when i click save button then calculation is performed after page refresh which is deals final price..

now because of ajax... values shoot to DB..

is there any way to set trigger on a specific column..

i am new to trigger that y have little knowledge.. need expert advice..

Cheers

edit: i want to set trigger on final_price column

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Comment: just need idea..possibility. if there is such a situation.. what is the best way..do do it..just any small example if u would like to show me.. situation is upthere ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a trigger on UPDATE and then inside the trigger check to see if the specified column was changed

```
CREATE TRIGGER sample_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON product_deals
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.final_price <> OLD.final_price THEN
    // put your code here
  END IF
END;
```